# PHP Image uploading

Tags: php, header

I  have a working script for image  uploading that is storing image data in binary format into mysql and when retrieving i am using header(content-type...).Is there any way to add some text contents to the page where the http header is going.

Comment: why are you storing images in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No

If you send an image via Content-Type then the browser expects the Content-Type. But you can dynamically add text to the image with the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Image Magick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library. Nevertheless it is not very performant to store images in mysql.

Comment: GD library..I guess ..I  should go  with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to store all the images in a directory, and create a page that shows the selected image + the text you want to add. So output that page as HTML, not as an image (so not setting Content-Type to image).

Answer (score 0):

Better save the images in a folder, in database just store their location.

Answer (score 0):

Try the imagecreatefromstring() method, documentation available in https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromstring.